# gdalcontour output not aligned with the DEM

Tags: gdal, gdal-contour

I use gdalcontour to generate the contour lines of a DEM in shapefile format. However the shapefile is not aligned with the DEM. Someone have a solution for this? GDAL version is 1.10

im using thins command:

```
gdal_contour -a height 012_merged.tif 012_contour.shp -i 25.0
```

[image]

gdalinfo:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: 012_merged.tif
       012_merged.tif.aux.xml
Size is 9601, 4801
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,0,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Mercator_1SP"],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    EXTENSION["PROJ4","+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +
x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext  +no_defs"],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","3857"]]
Origin = (-7124459.006549800700000,6446293.880868392100000)
Pixel Size = (23.191010033770905,-35.712191611463290)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-7124459.007, 6446293.881) ( 64d 0' 0.37"W, 50d 0' 0.37"N)
Lower Left  (-7124459.007, 6274839.649) ( 64d 0' 0.37"W, 48d59'59.54"N)
Upper Right (-6901802.119, 6446293.881) ( 61d59'59.80"W, 50d 0' 0.37"N)
Lower Right (-6901802.119, 6274839.649) ( 61d59'59.80"W, 48d59'59.54"N)
Center      (-7013130.563, 6360566.765) ( 63d 0' 0.09"W, 49d30' 9.16"N)
Band 1 Block=9601x110 Type=Int32, ColorInterp=Gray
  Description = Mosaicked Band
  Min=1.000 Max=305.000
  Minimum=1.000, Maximum=305.000, Mean=66.113, StdDev=78.056
  NoData Value=-32767
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=305
    STATISTICS_MEAN=66.11288340405
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=1
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=78.056016483986
```

Comment: Can you add ogrinfo of the shapefile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ran into the Pseudo Mercator bug.

This projection uses the WGS84 ellipsoid as a sphere with a=b. Many applications can not deal with this special projection. If possible, choose another projection, like pure WGS84 or UTM for your part of the world.

Or apply the projection to the shapefile with `ogr2ogr -a_srs` option, either EPSG:3857 (using the sphere) or EPSG:3395 (using the ellisoid).

Comment: do you why in EPSG:4326 gdaldem slope do no returns the same output than in EPSG:3857?

Comment: Maybe because horizontal units are degrees for the first one, and meters for the second.